# outputting each iteration of recursive function

Tags: php, function, fibonacci

Hi could someone tell me how to output each number in this fibonacci sequence while keeping it a recursive function so that instead of displaying the end number it displays the sequence of numbers.

thanks :-)

```
    <?php

    function fib($x){
    if($x <= 2){
    return 1;
    }

    return fib($x-1) + fib($x-2);
    }

    echo fib(10);

    ?>
```

Comment: put the echo INSIDE the function, obviously.

Comment: You should echo each result while calling `fib($x-1)`. So store it in a variable, then echo and return.

Comment: @Random that is not true.

Comment: @nl-x I Posted an answer expliciting the idea, which was, indeed, not complete :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is only echoing one number instead of all the number in a sequence is you're echoing the function call instead of when the function gets to a number in the sequence.

```
<?php

function fib($x){
  if($x <= 2){
    return 1;
  }

  echo $x . " ";

  return fib($x-1) + fib($x-2);
}

fib(10);
```

Call the fib() function and echo the number before recursively calling fib() again. Alternatively, you can put the `'echo $x . " ";'` before the 'if statement' at the beginning of the function if you'd like to echo the numbers that are also <= 2.

Comment: thanks A3, that helps alot. Why does it now output "10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 2 1 4 3 2 1 2 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 2 1 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 2 1 4 3 2 1 2 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 2 1 4 3 2 1 2 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 2 1 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 2 1 4 3 2 1 2 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 2 1 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 2 1 4 3 2 1 2" instead of the fibonacci sequence?

Answer (score 0):

You can't output the sequence in the recursive function, because the there is no 'sequence' being traversed. The recursive function kind-of forks each time with lower numbers until it hits the lowest number.

The function will in total be called an exponential time. For fib(5) the function is called 9 times, but for fib(10) the function is called 109 times!

If you put an echo inside the function, and you view the function calls as a tree, the echos traverse in a post-order manner:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To avoid performance leaks, you have to store the results you already computed. Then you just have to echo the one you compute, then will come in order.

```
$knownResults = array();
function fib($x){
    global $knownResults;
    if($x <= 2){
        return 1;
    }
    if(!array_key_exists($x-1, $knownResults)) {
        $knownResults[$x-1] = fib($x-1);
        echo "fib(".($x-1).") = ".$knownResults[$x-1]."\n";
    }

    if(!array_key_exists($x-2, $knownResults)) {
        $knownResults[$x-2] = fib($x-2);
        echo "fib(".($x-2).") = ".$knownResults[$x-2]."\n";
    }

    return $knownResults[$x-1] + $knownResults[$x-2];
}

echo "result: ".fib(40)."\n";
```